# json_pretty_print not working as expected

Tags: php, json

Although I've include the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT function in my code it is still displaying the content in one block of text. I've also tried using the `<pre></pre>` tags to show whitespace but this hasn't worked.

How can I display the text in a more readable format?

My code is as follows

```
$arrDetails[network]['network_id'] = 5;
$arrDetails['branch']['branch_id'] = 1556;

echo json_encode($arrRightmoveListing, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `json_encode()` should contain all the options logically OR'ed together, you're passing the pretty print option as the third argument. You want this:

```
echo json_encode($arrRightmoveListing, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```